# Chave estrangeira Entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Alguem pode me ajudar a fazer uma ligação entre essas duas tabelas, quero usar o campo matrícula para fazer essa ligação, sendo que matricula na tabela aluno não é a chave primária.

```
    public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int  IdAluno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha a escola!")]
    public int IdEscola { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a matrícula!")]
    public double matricula { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o nome do aluno!")]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a senha do aluno!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]

    public string senhaAluno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a senha do responsável!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]

    public string senhaResponsavel { get; set; }

    public virtual Escola escola { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<diarioAluno> diarioAluno { get; set; }
}

public class diarioAluno
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int IdDiarioAluno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha o diário!")]
    public int IdDiario { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a matrícula do aluno!")]
    public double matricula { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a ordem do aluno!")]
    public int ordem { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Marque, caso o aluno não estiver mais nesse diário!")]
    public bool situacao { get; set; }

    public virtual Diario diario { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno aluno { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Falta> falta { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Nota> notas { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Coloque o código não uma foto dele assim os membros poderão testa-lo

Comment: OK ! Desculpe, é minha primeira postagem...

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Comment: Sim, resolvi esse problema de uma outra forma. Obrigado